# Best way to change the "From" address on an arriving email in Outlook's VBA script?

Tags: vba, outlook

My overall goal is to change the "From" sender on an incoming email to something else.  Specifically, I get chat logs from Zopim chat and they're all coming from Zopim's "no-reply" email.  However, I want these chat logs to be associated with in my CRM and thus I want them associated to people who we chat with.

I've created this VBA script, it runs without errors, however, no change is done to the incoming email.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    Option Explicit

Sub ZopimChatMessageRule(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim body As String
    Dim sndr As String

    On Error GoTo Finally
    body = Trim(Right(Item.body, Len(Item.body) - (InStrRev(Item.body, "EMAIL") + 5)))
    sndr = Trim(Left(body, InStr(body, vbCrLf) - 1))

    Item.sender.Address = sndr
    Item.sender.Name = sndr
    Item.sender.Update

    Item.Recipients.ResolveAll
    Item.Save

Finally:

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sender` is read-only, even if you forward the mail, you could at best `SendOnBehalfOf`.    
How about simply changing the subject to "`From: [user] - [original subject]`" ?

Comment: Thx, dont think CRM picks up the subject :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is updating the name and address of a one-off address entry that does not exist anywhere. What you need to do is change the Sender and `SentOnBehalfOf` properties, which are read-only in the Outlook Object Model.

You can use `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` to update dozen or so `PR_SENDER_xyz` and `PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz` MAPI properties - take a look at a message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) (I am its author - click IMessage button). Keep in mind that `SetProperty` will prevent you from modifying some properties Outlook considers "special".

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am also its author), you can set the `Sender` and `SentOnBehalfOf` properties directly:

```
set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Msg = rSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(Item )
strEntryID = rSession.AddressBook.CreateOneOffEntryID("Fake User", "SMTP", "someuser@fake.domain.com", false, true)
set addressEntry = rSession.AddressBook.GetAddressEntryFromID(strEntryID)
Msg.Sender = addressEntry
Msg.SentOnBehalfOf = addressEntry
Msg.Save
```

Comment: I added in the Redemption COM library and selected it in references. when using the Code above it says for this: ```Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT```
method of data member not found

Comment: The script above assumes `Application` points to an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object (as would be the case in Outlook VBA). If you are running in a different environment (e.g. Excel VBA), `Application` intrinsic variable would point to an instance of the `Excel.Application` object. In that case, rename `Application` in the script above to something like `OutlookApp` and initialize it using `set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`.

Comment: Ok, I did the following above and it displayed a messageBox with the agreement and I selected yes and then it is now saying property is read only at ```Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")```

Comment: `Session` is also the property name of the `Application` object, and all of its properties are exposed as global objects. Try to rename the `Session` variable to something like `rSession` (see the updated script above).